# How to resume a segmented upload with openstack swift?

Tags: python, swift, openstack

I need to upload large (100-1000 GB) archive files to an OVH cloud archive. If the upload doesn't complete for any reason (for example the internet connection was lost) I would like to only upload the remaining segments.

I'm using the following command line (from a Python script):

`swift upload ulm-data/2021 /home/nodjo/my_file.zip --object-name my_file.zip  --skip-identical -S 147483648 --debug`

I thought --skip-identical would do the trick but all segments are uploaded again.

I've tried the following options with no luck: --leave-segments, -c, --ignore-checksum

Is there a way to achieve what I want to do?